# Ordinary differential equations of the form $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ question

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

An ODE of the form $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ is called "good" if $\frac{\partial (M(x,y))}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (N(x,y))}{\partial x}$

We are given the differential equation $(3x^2y+2xy+y^3)dx+(x^2+y^2)dy=0$. This ODE is not "good". We are asked to find $\mu (x,y)$ such that:

$$\mu (x,y)(3x^2y+2xy+y^3)dx+\mu (x,y)(x^2+y^2)dy=0,  (*)$$ 
is "good".

What I did:

if the equation $(*)$ is good then $\mu_y (x,y) M(x,y)+\mu (x,y)M_y (x,y)=\mu_x (x,y)N(x,y)+\mu (x,y)N_x (x,y)$

so we get

$\mu_y(x,y)(3x^2y+2xy+y^3)+\mu(x,y)(3x^2+2x+3y^2)=\mu_x(x,y) (x^2+y^2)+2x
\mu(x,y)$

And now I'm stuck.

Even if we were to guess $\mu_x(x,y)=0$ or $\mu_y(x,y)=0$ we will never get something like $\frac{\mu_y}{\mu}=\phi(y)$ or $\frac{\mu_x}{\mu}=\psi(x)$. $\mu$ seems to depend on both variables and unless the above restrictions apply (which they don't here) I don't know how to find $\mu$. Please help.

Comment: The standard terminology for 'good' is '*exact*'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is called either "exact" or "total". Never heard of "good".

Comment: Well, as long as the question was understandable...

Comment: And $\mu$ is called the 'integrating factor'

Comment: I can show you two ways. Do you only want an integrating factor to make it an exact DE and solve it or you accept other ways of solving it? There exists a beautiful one.

Comment: Try $\mu(x,y)=e^{3x}$.

Comment: Any way would be appreciated. by the way it turns out I was wrong, in our case the integrating factor is a function of $x$ only. BUT I would still love to know how to find it if it isnt the case.

Comment: @OriaGruber The ansatz $\mu_y(x,y)=0$ simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that:
$$
\frac{M_y - N_x}{N} = \frac{(3x^2 + 2x + 3y^2) - (2x)}{x^2 + y^2} = 3
$$
which is independent of $y$ (and also $x$, by conincidence). This suggests that we guess that $\mu_y = 0$ so that $\mu$ is a function of $x$ only. Thus, we obtain:
$$
\mu M_y = \mu_x N + \mu N_x \iff \frac{d\mu}{dx} = \frac{M_y - N_x}{N} \cdot \mu = 3\mu
$$
This ODE is separable/linear and can be easily solved to obtain $\mu(x) = e^{3x}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

**Hint**

Make the ansatz $\mu(x)$(the reason is explained in Adriano's answer)

$$(\mu (x)M(x,y))_y=(\mu (x)N(x,y))_x\iff (3x^2+2x+3y^2)\mu (x)=\mu (x)_x (x^2+y^2)+2x\mu (x)\iff \frac{\mu (x)_x}{\mu (x)}=3 \iff \mu (x)=e^{3x}$$

**Solution 2**

**Hint**

$$3x^2y+(x^2+y^2)y'+y^3+2xy=0\stackrel{y\colon =xv}{\iff} (x^2+x^2v^2)(xv'+v)+x^3v^3+3x^3v++2x^2v\;\stackrel{\text{simplify}}{\iff}\; v'=\frac{-v^3-xv^3-3v-3xv}{x(v^2+1)}\iff v'=-\frac{v(x+1)(v^2+3)}{x(v^2+1)}\iff \frac{v'(v^2+1)}{(v^2+3)v}=-\frac{x+1}{x}$$

Notation in case 1;

$X(a,b)_a\colon =\frac{\partial X(a,b)}{\partial a}$

Notation in case 2;

$(•)'\colon=\frac{\mathrm{d}•}{\mathrm{d}x}$